# Cannot access the items of the json array declared in EJS inside Javascript script tags

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

```
<div>  
    var arrayContent='<%= myJsonArray %>'
 <!--myJsonArray is sent to this ejs file using the render function in
 index.js while rendering this ejs file -->
</div>
<script>
  var index=0;
  function myfunc(){
  console.log(arrayContent); /*[object Object],[object Object],[object 
                                Object],[object Object] */

  var arrContentJson= JSON.parse(arrayContent);
  console.log(arrContentJson[index]); /* Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected 
                                         token o in JSON at position 1 */
   }
     </script>
```

Why am I not able to access the content of the parsed Json array (arrContentJson). How can I access it ?

Comment: `myJsonArray` is probably an array, not JSON representing an array. (You also have `<div>` tags here instead of `<script>`.) It isn’t safe to put arbitrary JSON directly in `<script>` tags, though; you need to use escaping specifically designed for that purpose. (If you implement that, you should test that it’s working by making sure `<` is escaped as `\x3c`.)

Comment: better to put a debug point at var arrayContent='<%= myJsonArray %>' and watch the variable content.

Comment: I think that the `console.log` logs you provided are not correct. Initially `arrayContent` is a string. How does it look like? The error you get should happen at the line with `JSON.parse()`

Comment: It looks like there's no need to call `JSON.parse()`. If you're passing JSON via an EJS template, it should load in that script as an object literal, not a string. Just remove the quotes around `<%= myJsonArray %>`

Comment: What confuses me is why you have JavaScript inside a `<div>`.

Comment: I have shown how the logs look like in comments @Sanka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to pass an array from ejs to the javascript code inside `<script>` tag, to do that you should use unescaped interpolation `<%- %>`:

```
<script>

    var arrayContent= <%- JSON.stringify(myJsonArray) %>;

    var index=0;

    function myfunc(){
        console.log(arrayContent);

        var arrContentJson= JSON.parse(arrayContent);
        console.log(arrContentJson[index]);
    }

    myfunc();

</script>
```

Comment: No it's not working. It's not giving any specific error as such. Just saying: 
myfunc is not defined.

Comment: Does `myJsonArray ` a json string or javascript object ?

Comment: It's a JSON array.

Comment: try to use `var arrayContent= <%- JSON.stringify(myJsonArray) %>;` instead

Comment: Okay this works and I'm able to get the elements out of arrayContent. But I have a doubt. 
What I know is that to access the elements of a JSON array, it should be a pure Json array and not a stringified version of it, right ? But in my case when I try to parse arrayContent which is a stringified version of JSON array back to JSON and access the element of the array like arrayContent[0].col[0], I get an error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" but when I'm accessing the elements from the stringified version i.e. directly from arrayContent without parsing it to JSON, it works! How ?

Comment: Let's agree first that we have 2 javascript interpreter, the first one on the server called nodejs and the second one on the browser, the browser execute javascript code inside the <script> tag, what you want to do is to define an array coming from node server inside the script tag (e.g `var arr = ['1', '2', '3']`), to get this working the array should be rendered as string (e.g `['1', '2', '3']`) that's why you need to transform your array into json string by using `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly removing the single quotes around the `'<%= myJsonArray %>'` will work, but it appears you're parsing already valid json. `console.log(arrayContent[0])` instead.

Comment: No it doesn't work. it gives me an error  
Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunc() is not defined. It doesn't give anything specific as such.
That is why I tried accessing myJsonArray as a String so that I could console it out and then I parse it back to JSON to access the content. Look at the console logs that I have commented. Thanks

Comment: [object Object],[object Object],...  implies one of 2 things: it's already correctly parsed json, meaning you don't need to JSON.parse() it, or that is the literal string content of the myJsonArray variable. I suspect 'myFunc()' is undefined because of a missing semicolon after the json without single quotes, but that begs the question why you're declaring the json outside the script element inside a div. this would be easy to debug in dev tools, is the output in the console.log a string or an object?

Comment: I know that it is parsed json but I had converted it into string so that I could log it out in the console. After that I'm parsing it back to Json so that I can access the content but I'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. My actual Json content is :
[
'col1':[
'data1',
'data2'
],
'col2':[
'data1',
'data2'
],
'col3':[
'data1',
'data2'
],
'col4':[
'data1',
'data2'
]
]

Comment: you can log objects to the console, they don't have to be strings.

Comment: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" means it's trying to parse the string '[object Object... ' as json, which means the `'<%= myJsonArray %>'` is a string containing the text '[object Object...'. remove the quotes, add a semicolon, and don't JSON.parse() it. you'll be able to access arrayContent[0] at that point.

Comment: I tried doing what you said. The error Unexpected token o in JSON at pos 1 has gone but again it gives an error function not defined. That means there is something wrong with the code inside the function and all I'm trying to do inside the function body is to access the JSON array content. So it's still not accessible.